# Extract number from string php

Tags: php

I have a string: "Суспензия для инъекций 0,5 мл, 1,0 мл, 5 мл"
Float numbers here are divided by comma, and comma may also appear as a classical word divider. I should get all numbers in output:
0,5; 1,0; 5
I tried something with this one:

```
$form = $d->drugForm;
preg_match_all('!\d+(?:\.\d+)?!', $form, $matches);
```

But seems to be it skips comma and hence in output I got 0, 1, 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regexp should be:

```
$re = "/(\\d+,?\\d*)/";
$str = "Суспензия для инъекций 0,5 мл, 1,0 мл, 5 мл, 12,1234";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gD2nC8/2)

Comment: no interegers now Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 0,5 [1] => 1,0 )

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $form, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Your regexp doesn't work. Not capturing numbers and also not working searching correct numbers.

Comment: floats are still skipped

Answer (score 0):

```
$re = "/(\d+(,)?(\d+)?)/";
$str = "Суспензия для инъекций 0,5 мл, 1,0 мл, 5 мл, 12,1234";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```